# mysql order by clause not working with my query

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT friends.id, sum(if(friends.online =1,1,0)) AS online_friends, ...,...
FROM some_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum(if(friends.online =1,1,0)) ASC;
```

What I want is to sort my resulting table bases on online_friends either ASC or DESC, the problem is that this query does not sort them by online_friends.

Can anyone help me fixed my query?

This is an example of the results

```
id      group         online_friends
--     -------       ---------------- 
1       west               5
2       east               3
3       north              7
4       south              2
```

I want to sort the results based on online_friends

Comment: You query from `some_table` but your columns are qualified like `friends.id`. I think there's something about this query you're not telling us.

Comment: i just made the query up, it might not make sense. What I basically want is to sort by the result of online_friends. Ill make a result table to demonstrate it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work:

```
SELECT friends.id, sum(if(friends.online =1,1,0)) AS online_friends, ...,...
FROM friends
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum(if(friends.online =1,1,0)) ASC;
```

However, I would write it as:

```
SELECT friends.id, sum(friends.online = 1) AS online_friends, ...,...
FROM friends
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum(friends.online = 1) ASC;
```

You can also change the `order by` to:

```
ORDER BY online_friends
```

If you find that it still doesn't work, then please set up a SQL Fiddle so we can see what is happening.

Comment: your right, it should work. but somehow it doesnt work on my stored procedure. It must be something else wrong with my procedure

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SELECT friends.id, groups, sum(friends.online) AS online_friends
FROM some_table
where friends.online = 1
GROUP BY friends.id, groups
ORDER BY friends.online ASC;
```

I assumed that online and offline are having the value as 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: I am passing the order by clause  as a parameter to a stored procedure. Is there a way to do in the order clause?

Comment: @user3768541:- I am not sure if I get your question correctly but how are you passing the order by clause as input parameter. I dont think it is possible or rather a good approach to proceed with.